# SAP HANA vs Exasol

Tags: bigdata

I am interested in knowing the differences in **functionality** between SAP HANA and Exasol. Since this is a bit of an open ended question let me be clear. I am not interested in people debating which is "better" or faster. I am only interested in what each was designed to do so please keep your opinions out of it. I suspect it is a bit like comparing HANA to Oracle Exalytics where there is some overlap but the functionality goals are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not an enormous difference between what you can do with the two databases, it's more a question of the focus and the way the functionality is implemented and that's where it becomes difficult to explain without using words like "better" and "faster" (and for sure words like "cheaper")

EXASOL was designed for speed and ease of use with Analytical processing and is designed to run on clusters of commodity hardware. SAP is a more complex, aims to do more than "just" Analytical processing and runs only on a range of "approved" hardware.

What type of differences did you have in mind ?

Comment: I am interested in analytics. I know HANA has a lot of transnational functionality but I am more interested what can be done in terms of machine learning, custom python reducers and hive interface. For example I know HANA has an library of machine learning algorithms built right in. Does Exasol?

Comment: EXASOL has a framework called "EXAPowerlytics" which uses protobuf and ZeroMQ to connect with Hadoop (for example). It also allows the ability to write User Defined Functions in Java, Lua, Python and R - for example importing any R machine-learning libraries you need without limit and running them in-memory and in parallel (where the algorithm is parallelisable). Definitely recommend signing-up at [link](www.exasol.com/portal) to get some more information.